# Storing Data in a web application

Tags: javascript, storage

I'm a high school student in the process of creating a fairly simple quiz-like app as an attempt to learn more about coding. My goal with the app is to have the user answer a few questions which will have each answer associated with a value, and the final result will be sum of all of the values.

I just don't know how to store the data/values that the user selects in order to use them later to create an end sum. Should I associate each value with a variable to use later? If so, how?

Here's a fiddle of an example question from my ideal quiz: http://jsfiddle.net/J7m7m/342/.

```js
function changeText(value) {
    document.getElementById('count').value = 100 * value;
}
```

```html
<h1>Personal information</h1>
    
<h2>Ability</h2>
    
<input type="radio" onclick="changeText(.5)" name="group2" />Beginner</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="changeText(.3)" name="group2" />Intermediate</label>
<input type="radio" onclick="changeText(.15)" name="group2" />Advanced</label>
</div>
<h3/>Likelihood of Injury (%)
<input type="text" id="count" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascripts localStorage Objects. Your values get stored in the Browser for as long as you wish, or the browser is deleted.

Take a look at [w3cschools explaination](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and further information on Web Storage:

> The localStorage Object
>
> The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The
>   data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be
>   available the next day, week, or year.
>
> Example:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use javaScript objects to store your data at the frontend.
You may directly pass this object by encoding with json on the server to store it to database.
Example :

```
var g_obj = new Object();
g_obj.level = new Object();
g_obj.level.diff = "Beginner";
g_obj.level.injury = "50";
g_obj.answers = new Array();
g_obj.answers[0] = new Object();
g_obj.answers[0].id = "1";
g_obj.answers[0].correct = "1";
g_obj.answers[0].marks = 10;
g_obj.answers[1] = new Object();
g_obj.answers[1].id = "2";
g_obj.answers[1].correct = "0";
g_obj.answers[1].marks = 10;
g_obj.answers[2] = new Object();
g_obj.answers[2].id = "3";
g_obj.answers[2].correct = "1";
g_obj.answers[2].marks = 15;
```

Comment: I would use a combination of objects/arrays as mentioned here and JavaScript sessionStorage or localStorage in order to build up a store of your question results whilst the user progresses through the quiz. Bear in mind that if you use sessionStorage, your data will be lost if the browser is closed.

Comment: Correct!!! Ideally for creating the online test scenario, I would suggest you to create ajax calls and store it to database each time the user selects an answer or clicks next question. The object thus created can be used to do so. In this case even if the user closes the browser and returns back, you can always repopulate the object created from database.

Comment: You can also store the json decoded array object to database by serializing it...Hey There are lots of options open for you... Do it your way...

Answer (score -1):

What are the requirements for the storage?

- Do you want to store data local or serverside?
- Should it be secure? DB backend password protected
- How many storage you think you need?
- Is it mandatory that the data will be persistent?

If you are happy with 5mb max semi-persistent storage unsecurely stored clientside: Localstorage, or IndexedDB(200mb)

If you want to secure your data, you have to need to create a database like MySQL and some back end controller to handle the requests from your web application.

I think localStorage is the best option for you :)

Comment: Please try not to be a smartass. It is not very helpful for people who just learn basics, to throw rocks of metaquestions at them. This is a high school task, not an MIT Paper. ;)

Comment: @mondjunge Are you insulting me? I am giving him basic options of possible webstorage.  I don't ask him what kind of data storage engine  or database structure he wants. Be calm and let questioner ask for clarification if he wants it. This is not an helpdesk.

Comment: They are not "basic options" though. Not for a high school project. A basic option would be storing data in localStorage or even to file.

Comment: @com2ghz: No, I am helping you to improve your answer style, so you won't get downvotes in the future. If I would be up to insult you, I could just show why asking for "local or clientside storage" is totally wrong (WTF is local vs. clientside storage?) Or what security has to to with a db password protection or since when you ask for "many storage" when you should ask for "how much storage" or that you possibly did not read the question when asking if persistance of data is mandatory. Should I go on, or do you agree that "Don't be a smartass" is a very nice way to put it.